# Set Caret position with JTextArea in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, caret

Right now I have a JTextArea inside of a JScrollPane. For the current content it has both a vertical and horizontal scroll bar showing up. I'm trying to implement a search functionality where a user can search for a certain string and it will set the caret position to the first occurrence of that string. However it seems that JScrollPane only scrolls vertically when I set my caret position. So matching strings going off the JTextArea horizontally will completely get missed and the horizontal scroll bar won't scroll at all.

I'm using the basic function
`setCaretPosition()` for the JTextArea

Does anybody have any idea why my JScrollPane isn't moving horizontally using `setCaretPosition()`

**Edit:**

It appears the horizontal scroll bar is scrolling but it moves so little that it's barely noticeable. I can only see the very first pixel of the character. Is there a way to have the scrollbar center (or as much as possible) to the caret position?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html) that demonstrates the problem.  Or at least, what you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [Visible Caret Listener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/no-wrap-text-pane/).

Or you can also look at [Center Line in Scroll Pane](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/04/center-line-in-scroll-pane/). It only centers the line vertically, but you could customize the code to do horizontal as well.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, these examples helped tremendously.